# Highchart bubbles with arrows inside

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I want to draw a bubble chart using Highcharts with an arrow or a pointer that points to a certain position on the circumference of the bubble depending upon a data value.

Think of it like this: each bubble is like a gauge without any calibrations. It has just a dial which points to a single point on the bubble surface, preferably on the inside.

This is an example image of the bubble for reference:

[image]

Is this possible? Or am I reaching?

Comment: If someone is looking for the solution, it has been answered on highcharts forum http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/bubble-charts-with-arrow-pointers-t36575/

Comment: Thank you @morganfree. I was the one who posted that question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the Highcharts forum where I'd posted the same question:

http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/bubble-charts-with-arrow-pointers-t36575/